# Passing data between seperate JavaScript files from functions

Tags: javascript, export

I have a function that takes the price of a stock, runs it through a function changePrice() and outputs a new price of the stock stored in variable newPrice.

Is there a way to "pass" or access this newPrice variable in another Javascript file I wish to use it in?

```
function stocks() {

companies = [
      {
          name : 'Apple'
        , symbol : 'AAPL'
        , price : '100'
        , shares : '0'
      }]
      
      for (var key in companies) {
        var obj = companies[key];
            
            for (var prop in obj) {
            
            if (prop === 'price') {
                    var priceOfThisStock = parseFloat(obj[prop]);
                    
                    obj[prop] = changePrice(priceOfThisStock); 
                    
                    var newPrice = obj[prop]
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This depends on what you exactly mean by *separate files*. Does it mean that the one JS file is called on one page and the other on another page? Or does it mean you have two JS files, which are both used on one page at the same time?

Comment: I have two JS files used on one HTML page at the same time I just used them to seperate the work. The other file is a function to plot the data on a graph and I just wanted to send the newPrice to the graph.js file to plot it.

Comment: Now it depends on how you really call the graph.js code. Please give us some more details

Comment: the graph.js code is run directly from index.html file and injects the graph into the page after the html and other JS has parsed, so I havent directly called the graph.js from another JS file yet.

Comment: If I have a function inside another function it does not appear to be in the global scope of my project to use..this seems to be the problem when calling it. What would be the proper way to globally call a function in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options you can use to transfer variables between js scripts.

**Import the value through an instance of a function:**

- Import second js file into the same document as the first (using html)
- Create an instance of a function from the second file below `var newPrice = obj[prop]`
- Make the value parsed into the function public within the second file

**Import through the URL (for non-sensitive data)**

- UrlEncode the data
- Use `window.location.href = 'newpage.html?' + urlEncodedData`
- Import the second file into newpage.html
- Fetch the GET data in the second file
- UrlDecode the data

You can also do this with aid from php and using JS libraries like jQuery. We need to know a bit more about what the files are being used in and whether you are importing them into html.

Comment: Hi, Just noticed there is a slight typo incase you didn't notice it. Where I put "window.location.href" you need to redirect to the newpage.html with the UrlEncoded data which would look like: "newpage.html?val1=one&val2=two